# Async WCF calls in a loop using tasks

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf, task-parallel-library

I'm writing a WPF application that needs to make numerous calls to a WCF services based on items in a list.

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
    var dataAboutItem = MethodThatCallsWCFService(item);

    //  Do work to update UI
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Is there a smart way to do this using Tasks/Parallel.ForEach or some construct in the TPL that will let me make all the service calls on background threads and then update the UI accordingly as results come in for each call?

Comment: I'm not right now but there's nothing stopping me.  It's essentially a one time use application I'm writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use C# 5.0, then `async`-`await` can help you with this. The code generator for WCF services supports `async`-`await`, so it can generate async versions of your methods, which will be useful.

What you would do is to start all of the requests asynchronously, and store the `Task`s they return in a collection. Then, process the `Task`s as they complete. .Net doesn't support that out of the box, but you can use [Stephen Toub's `Interleaved()` method](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/08/02/processing-tasks-as-they-complete.aspx):

```
var tasks = new List<Task<DataAboutItem>>();

foreach (var item in items)
{
    // don't await here yet
    Task<DataAboutItem> dataAboutItemTask = MethodThatCallsWCFServiceAsync(item);

    tasks.Add(dataAboutItemTask);
}

foreach (var bucket in Interleaved(tasks))
{
    var dataAboutItemTask = await bucket;
    DataAboutItem dataAboutItem = await dataAboutItemTask;

    //  Do work to update UI
}
```

If you wanted to throttle calling the WCF service (for example, only make 10 requests at a time), you could instead use TPL Dataflow, specifying `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`.

Comment: I think I understand what's happening in the second await but what about the first one?  Please forgive my ineptness.

Comment: It's mostly an artifact of how the ordering of `Task`s works. When you start iterating the collection, it has to immediately give you a `Task`, but it doesn't know which one will finish first yet. So the return type of `Interleaved()` is actually `Task<Task<T>>[]`, which is why you need two `awaits`. It's all explained in the article I linked to.

Comment: Cool.  I'm going to take this approach.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Task Parallel Library

[Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx)

Last sample has UI

[Potential Pitfalls in Data and Task Parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997392.aspx)

Or update a public property the UI is bound to rather than the UI directly.

If this is not going to load CPU you may want to use MaxDegreeOfParallelism to keep too many thread from spinning up.

[ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx)